# Get started with celery and rabbitmq using python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

i have two files task1.py and task2.py where i have defined two functions and it is stored in a linux server. 
The first file is

```
from celery import Celery
import sys
app = Celery('task1',backend='amqp://' ,broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def get_sum():
        try:
                a = 3
                b = 3
                c = a + b
                return c
        except:
                return sys.exc_info()[0]
```

The second file is

```
 from celery import Celery
    import sys
    app = Celery('task2',backend='amqp://' ,broker='amqp://')

    @app.task
    def get_product():
            try:
                    a = 3
                    b = 3
                    c = a * b
                    return c
            except:
                    return sys.exc_info()[0]
```

I have called this task1 and and task2 in 2 other files as

```
from task1 import get_sum
from celery.exceptions import TimeoutError
result = get_sum.delay()
try:
        print result.get()
except:
        print result.state
```

I am able to initiate a single worker and run the file but when i define multiple workers and run the single file all the worker process stop. 
I tried using this command

```
celery multi start 3 -c 3
celery worker -n celery1@myhost -c 3
celery worker -n celery2@myhost -c 3
celery worker -n celery3@myhost -c 3
```

I know i m doing it wrong. Can some one guide me how to initiate multiple workers and run multiple files at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should only have 1 celery object. Move it to another file (task.py) and launch  `celery worker --app=task.app --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=3`